# Automatically force quit frozen applications in OSX maybe using a ruby script?

Tags: ruby, command-line, terminal, osx-mavericks

I built an application using openframeworks that is live 24/7 on a kiosk. Every now and then (every few weeks) it will randomly go unresponsive and I still can't get to the bottom of it because it's so random and infrequent it is hard to debug.

I wrote a ruby script that looks for the application running and if it doesn't exist it will start it up. This works in all cases where the application name doesn't show up in activity monitor. Meaning if the app crashes and completely force quits itself or something. It works just fine.

However, if the app just freezes and goes unresponsive (red highlight in activity monitor) the app doesn't quit out completely unless I force quit manually. Is there some kind of script I can write to look for all "unresponsive apps/processes" every few seconds and force quits them automatically? That way my app launcher script will be able to detect that the app isn't running and boot it up again.

Comment: Here's a script that detects unresponsive apps: http://superuser.com/questions/688024/how-can-i-determine-if-an-application-is-not-responding

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) because it's solid, well tested, well documented, and easy to learn.

If you still want to write your own monitoring script, Monit is a good example to follow.

The most reliable way to detect an unresponsive app is to have a "vital sign" which is a generic term for a signal that an app emit to prove it's healthy. Some people call this a "pulse" or "heartbeat" or "brainwave". Your external script watches the vital sign. If your external script sees the vital sign flatline, then the script takes action to cure the app or restart it.

An alternate way is to have a "ping" which is a generic term for your external script sending a signal to the app or the system, then listening for a reply. You can use tools such as the Unix `ps` command for processes, or AppleScript Activity Monitor. As far as I know, these do a pretty good job of catching common cases, but have trouble catching apps that are soaking up resources, such as being caught in endless loops.